# Bishop explains a law of robotics after the "knife game" in which he injures himself -- inconsistent?

Tags: robots, aliens-1986, laws-of-robotics

It seems to me that Bishop explaining to Ripley the Asimovian law which controls his behavior is not really consistent.

Firstly, you could argue that the subject of the game, Paxton's character Hudson (and Paxton's character in Terminator also has a problem with an android -- coincidence?), was subject to psychological harm. Moreover, Bishop ignores his wishes, proceeding despite Hudson's protestations to play the game where he places his own hand over the humans and then moves a knife at superhuman speed between both of their fingers. Bishop says, Trust me, in a sincere-sounding way and indeed Hudson suffers no physical injury.

Is this really how an android governed by the law Bishop informs Ripley of, especially since Bishop actually did cut himself. Would not an android governed by the Asimovian law err on the side of caution, in addition to obeying a human's wishes to even not play the "game"?

Comment: With typical Asimovian sophistry you could argue that trauma is an experience that broadened Hudsons horizon in some fashion and thus resulted in a net benefit for him. That the laws of robotics are now always applied according to human intution was always a big part of the robot stories. On the other hand, I might be overthinking this :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's not apparent that Bishop is bound by the literal [three Laws of Robotics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=63&v=MsvdXY4lZag&feature=youtu.be). He certainly seems to be bound by a version of the First Law of Robotics (which he describes as being part of his 'behavioural inhibition programming') but on several occasions he causes harm to himself and fails to obey direct orders given by human beings, so it's pretty clear that Law #2 and Law #3 aren't absolutes for him, even if he is broadly programmed to obey military orders and programmed for self-preservation.

The film's [official novelisation](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Aliens_(novel)) gives us some additional insight into this.

> Well, that explains it. The old A/2s were always a bit twitchy. That could never happen now, not with the new implanted behavioral inhibitors. **Impossible for me to harm or, by omission of action, allow to be harmed a human being. The inhibitors are factory-installed**, along with the rest of my cerebral functions. No one can tamper with them. So you see, I’m quite harmless." He offered her a plate piled high with yellow rectangles. "More corn bread?”
>
> [later]
>
> It was presented to Bishop. Android or not, he had the final say.
> Along with a multitude of other human emotions **the new synthetics were
> also fully programmed for self-preservation.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Aliens - Official Novelisation](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Aliens_(novel))</sup></sub>

It's pretty clear that Bishop is intelligent enough to identify that the net damage to Hudson is going to be pretty small. He's not going to come to *physical* harm and will probably be [laughing and joking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55a3rDrjdfI) in a few minutes time. The experience may even help him to prove his bravado to the other marines.